# Why nodeagent can't be started from Dmgr? Can someone please explain me the logic behind it

Tags: websphere-8

Why nodeagent can't be started from Dmgr? Can someone please explain me the logic behind it.Though we can stop it from dmgr.

Answer (score 3):

The dmgr uses the nodeagent process to execute commands on a remote machine.  In theory, an alternative would be to use ssh to execute remote commands, but WebSphere Application Server does not use SSH because it would add too much extra complexity (SSH keys, OS user ID management, not easily supported on all platforms supported by WebSphere, etc.).  Consequently, when the nodeagent is down, there is no way for the dmgr to execute a startNode.sh/.bat command on the remote machine to start it.  In theory, the dmgr could execute the command itself if the node is on the same machine, but IBM doesn't recommend putting the dmgr and other nodes on the same machine anyway, so there's no reason to add that capability.

Answer (score 0):

Nodeagent is a type of websphere process that is used to manage other websphere processes and is connected with dmgr through proprietary communication protocols.

In case nodeagent is down there is no way for dmgr process to reach it and start it. You should need another kind of nodeagent to manage the nodeagent or a OS mechanism to handle this but unfortunatelly this is not the case for Websphere Architecture.

However if you need it you can send a **restart command** from the dmgr to the nodeagent.